# Powershell: Read csv and create hashtable, then use data in hashtable to do calculation?

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file which contains the following table

```
 Name    X      Y     Z
 Al      50    1900   15
 Steel   30    5700   15
```

Basically, the row starts with 'Name' is the header row. I want to firstly read this CSV in powershell and create a hashtable. After that I need to read the data from the hashtable and do a simple calculation. For example, if I use `$Hashtable.Al`, then I can get the value of `X,Y,Z`. And the following equation could be `$Q = $X+$Y+$Z`so that I can get the answer of `$Q`. (The `$Hashtable.Steel`should work in the same way.)

```
    #Read CSV and Create the hashtable

    #Read data -X Y Z from hashtable by using
    $Al = $Hashtable.Al

    #Do a simple calculation
    $Q = $Al.X + $Al.Y + $Al.Z
    $Q
```

Comment: So `$Hashtable.Al` should return an array containing the values of `X`, `Y` and `Z` for the correponding row in the CSV?

Comment: We are not going to write your code for you. If you're not sure how to do it then look it up. You already have a plan described with the comments. Search for each of them and you will get what you need. If you get into a specific problem, ask here and we will try to help. Hint: `Import-CSV`. Also, if you're going to to the same calculation for every object (line: Al, Steel etc.) I would use an array instead of a hashtable.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, you are right. I just updated my description. I want to use the value of X,Y,Z to do the calculation.

Comment: @FrodeF. I can now read the CSV file, but can only do two headers, `Name` and `X`.                                                                                                       `$t = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Shuai\Desktop\CSV\Database.csv' -Header "Name", "x", "Y", "Z"
$Hashtable = @{ }
Foreach ($r in $t)
{
 Write-Host $r.Name $r.X $r.Y $r.Z
 $Hashtable.Add($r.Name, $r.X, $r.Y, $r.Z)
}`

Comment: You need to add the object (that import-csv creates for each line) to the hashtable, not the individual values. You can access them later using the properties in the object you stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Name` value is unique for each row, this is super easy:

```
# Create hashtable
$HashTable = @{}

# Import CSV
$CSV = Import-Csv .\Path\To\Csv\File.csv

# Iterate over the CSV rows and populate the hashtable:
$CSV |ForEach-Object { $HashTable[$_.Name] = $_ }
```

If you want to make sure that the objects contained in `$HashTable` *only* has the `X`,`Y` and `Z` properties, use `Select-Object` when you assign them:

```
$CSV |ForEach-Object { $HashTable[$_.Name] = $_ |Select-Object X,Y,Z }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is very old however, I was looking at it to solve something.
I have a fairly large CVS file (100,000 rows with about 20 columns) and needed 2 columns stored in a hash for further processing.
Timing things with measure-object, I found Get-Content to be orders of magnitudes faster than import-csv to ingest the data.
Using the data from the string array to set up the hash is also faster than iterating over the resulting CSV object.
I tested both scenarios in code and repeatedly found the results to be consistent while comparing apples to apples.